# Error while Configuring Yarn on a Slurm Cluster with Hadoop HDFS

Tags: hdfs, hadoop-yarn, slurm

I'm encountering an issue when configuring Yarn on a Slurm cluster alongside Hadoop HDFS. I have a Slurm batch script that launches nodes and dynamically edits core-site and yarn-site configuration files based on the allocated nodes. However, when it comes to configuring hdfs-site.xml for the dfs.datanode.data.dir property, I have defined a static path, for which, I'm encountering the following error:

ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Unable to acquire file lock on path .../hadoop-3.3.5/for_datanode_dir/for_host_gpu10/in_use.lock
ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: It appears that another node 3710@gpu09.cluster has already locked the storage directory: .../hadoop-3.3.5/for_datanode_dir/for_host_gpu10
java.nio.channels.OverlappingFileLockException

I'm seeking assistance in resolving this issue.